# As a pianist, am I a philistine for secretly hating Chopin?

Tags: piano, chopin

I am a pianist – not a terribly good one; I got ABSRM Grade 8 as a teenager and now (~20 years later) have moved mostly onto voice but I continue to play the piano both for fun and occasionally for rehearsal purposes with others. Over the years I have slowly got better at sight reading (in particular 4-part SATB style choral music, which I do a lot) and I enjoy playing the piano "for fun", often either with romantic composers like Beethoven, more impressionist Debussy or Satie, or (post-)modern composer's piano works like Alessandra Celletti or Joe Hisaishi. I see the value of playing scales and exercises, and I do so regularly. I try to keep it up and I find playing a nice mix of stimulating and relaxing.

I've got a very clichéd "big book of piano greats" which I am currently working my way through. This includes, amongst many other things, in my mind, a disproportionate amount of Chopin. I *never* liked Chopin – one of my grade 8 pieces was one of his nocturnes -- and although I can badly bash my way though most of the works in the book, they don't seem musical and the main challenge to that is his stereotypical left hand, with chords in three. I can't find a way to make music out of this other than by memorising the position of each chord. Unlike, say, Beethoven, whose insane chords always seem to just fall under my fingers, Chopin's left hand drives me mad. Even Liszt is more 'fun'.

So, whilst in the title of this question I have provocatively written "am I a philistine?" in disliking Chopin this way, I guess I really want to ask:

1. Would a different practice style encourage me to "enjoy" playing these pieces more?
2. Assuming my experience is not unique (Chopin's "left hand" is quite famous) -- what do others *like* about playing his works? What can I focus on instead, other than a huge sense of frustration that I haven't put the hours in to memorise all the fast leaps?
3. Chopin is consistently rated highly among the most important piano composers and has contributed a lot to the repertoire. Why? Is it for the musicological reason that his technique and pieces were undoubtedly novel at the time, and the development (in particular) of more "crunchy" harmonies moved the world on to exploring more interesting chords?

Comment: I think this is likely to get closed as 'opinion-based', but in the meantime, why not learn to have fun with it, mix it up a bit. This is a friend of mine's take on Cole Porter, done in the style of Chopin - [When Cole Met the Pole](https://harrythepiano.bandcamp.com/track/when-cole-met-the-pole) [bandcamp link]

Comment: Everyone will have their loves/likes/dislikes/hates especially when it comes to art-inspired subjects, and music is certainly one. Just because a piece (or those of a composer) are clever, challenging, boring or whatever, just means the potential adoring audience will be smaller.We do have 'rules' in music, but none of them say you have to play/enjoy/endure everything. Worth a look at all the 'great' composers, but feel free to eschew those who're maybe not on your wavelength - right now! Sorry, but this will likely be closed as subjective and opinionated.

Comment: Just a note: when I saw the title, I rushed to be ready to close it as opinion-based, but the actual body of the question contains at least two ( 2 1/2?) insightful and objective questions. I suggest editing the “shock – value“ title.

Comment: A loophole in the logic: Someone can be highly represented in the literature of an instrument without necessarily being fun to play: Either their work is *good* for you (I don't know that anyone plays Hanon for fun), or they're one of "the greats" because of their accomplishment even if it's hard for the rest of us (I don't find Paganini very "fun").

Comment: I suggest rewriting this question to focus specifically on one problem you've encountered in Chopin and how to practice it.

Comment: You aren't a philistine for disliking Chopin, but it sounds like you've not had the sorts of good experiences with his music that would help you develop a more informed opinion. I suggest that you seek out good recordings--of which there are plenty--to find fresh ways of hearing this music. Spend time with them, and you may find your opinion changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a fluent left hand to play Chopin effectively.  And as yours becomes more fluent you'll be able to better recognise the patterns in Chopin's LH parts.

Sometimes a lot of the satisfaction in playing a piece comes from the knowledge that you HAVE overcome the technical difficulties.   Perhaps you're a Chopin listener more than a Chopin player.